How to implement the animated modal component from Aceternity UI in my code (next js+ TypeScript)?
Link to the mentioned modal component:  https://ui.aceternity.com/components/animated-modal
I have searched all over the internet for an example but there is no example anywhere. There are no examples  in the official docs as well.
I have a button "Details" which when clicked should show a pop up modal which just needs to display an image . The modal should have just a close sign. The modal should also close back down when clicked anywhere else on the screen except the modal.
I have installed Aceternity UI, the animated modal component, but I am not sure how to integrated it in my code.
Is there a better, easier way of doing this maybe without a component from Aceternity UI?
My best guess:
import {
  ModalProvider,
  Modal,
  ModalBody,
} from "../components/ui/animated-modal";
const Patents = () => {
    const [open, setOpen]= useState(false);
    
    

    <Button
    onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
    className="mt-2 px-3 py-3 rounded-xl bg-black dark:bg-white dark:text-black text-white text-md font-bold"
    > Details</Button>
    
                <ModalProvider setOpen={setOpen} open={open}>
                  <Modal>
                    <ModalBody>
                      <img
                        src="/patent1.png"
                        alt="large"
                        className="object-contain h-[80vh] w-[70vw]"
                        />
                    </ModalBody>
                  </Modal>
                </ModalProvider>

